# Действительное и страдательное причастие (вопрос на сообразительность)

Tags: семантика

Есть ли в русском языке глаголы, действительное и страдательное причастие от которых, означают одно и то же?

(Формулировка - не очень строгая, это экспромт)

//-------------------

Короче, я крепко засомневался в вопросе.
Я говорил о парах "зависящий-зависимый" (абсолютные синонимы) "значащий-значимый" (близкие синонимы) и, возможно, еще каких-то. 
Словари отказывают "страдательным" вариантам в праве быть причастиями, но если это прилагательные, то все равно - отглагольные.

Я вообще не вижу веских причин (кроме традиции) разделять эти части речи, а в данном случае - тем более. Но формально получается, что формулировка не проходит...

//-------------------
[[@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)

> Руководимый и управляемый - это тоже прилагательные по той же причине.

Не знаю, по какой причине Вы этого не знаете, но это вполне себе причастия. Во всяком случае никто пока не доказал иное.  
http://www.pedlib.ru/Books/6/0262/6_0262-302.shtml  
Другое дело, что по мнению Розенталя со товарищи эти причастия образованы от глаголов, ранее бывших переходными, но это совсем другой разговор.

Давайте пока не ставить телегу впереди лошади. Образование от переходных глаголов - не абсолютное характеристическое, данное "по определению", свойство страдательных причастий и не критерий принадлежности к данной части речи, а всего лишь некоторый статистический признак, которым надо пользоваться с осторожностью.

Answer (score 1):

Обессилеть-обессилевший, обессиленный
обескроветь-обескровленный, обескровевший

Comment: Это не совсем синонимы. Обессиленный кем, обессилевший - сам. Обескровленный - аналогично, даже ещё дальше.
Но в принципе - да, речь об этом. Вам долго пришлось искать пары? 
Я на тот предмет, насколько эта задачка олимпиадная.

Comment: Олимпиадная конечно. Ученики вряд ли догадаются быстро. А насчёт синонимов: глаголы обессилеть и обессилить как раз и разводят значения(обессилеть-сам,обессилить - кого-то),я дала форму с -еть и 
-евший (в отличие от обессиливший кого-то), а вот обессиленный - и то, и другое значение(и от обессилеть, и от обессилить)

Comment: Да я не про учеников... ну или не только для них. ;)

Еще есть подобные пары? Я знаю одну совершеннейших на мой взгляд синонимов, но вот сомневаюсь, насколько это именно причастия.

Comment: Не знаю, о каких парах Вы говорите, но это многие из глаголов с приставкой обез/обес со значением "лишиться самому",они образуют действительный и страдательный залог со значением "лишивший себя, оказавшийся лишённым чего-то":Обезножеть-обезножевший, обезноженный(лишившийся ног, лишённый ног), 
обезводеть-обезводевшая местность, обезвоженная местность(лишившаяся воды, лишённая воды). А Вы что имеете в виду?

Comment: Я говорю о паре синонимов, один  из которых действительное, а другой - страдательное причастия *от одного и того же глагола.* 
Ваши пары - весьма условные синонимы.

Comment: Зависимый - это прилагательное (постоянный признак), зависящий - это причастие (процессуальный признак), употребляется с зависимыми словами. Возможно, здесь обычный переход причастие в прилагательное сопровождался изменением формы, то есть заменой суффиксов?

Comment: >Зависимый - это прилагательное (постоянный признак), зависящий - это причастие (процессуальный признак),   

Или наоборот. "Уравнение, зависящее от параметра" - это что, процессуальный признак?  
  
А "зависимая переменная" в этом уравнении - постоянный?

Вы так говорите, потому, что знаете, что "зависимый" - прилагаьеное. Не из какому контекста это не вытекает. 

Руководимый иди управляемый - это торе "прилагательные"?!

Comment: Грамматика  изучает формы речи, и она вещь во многом условная. Например, глагол как часть речи обозначает процесс, а причастие (как форма глагола) - процессуальный признак. Уравнение зависит от параметра - это процесс; уравнение, зависящее от параметра, - это процессуальный признак. Слово "зависимый" не может быть страдательным причастием прошедшего времени, так как образуется от непереходного глагола.Руководимый и управляемый - это тоже прилагательные по той же причине.